# how should i include the link in bootstrap for form validation

Tags: javascript, java, sql, jsp, bootstrap-4

[i have done like in picture but it is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvr3G.png)

Comment: Please don't use pictures to share your code. Copy-paste it with the question.

Comment: Hey try my answer and let me know whether It worked for you or not?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `script tag` instead try `link tag` as shown below:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet">
```